# HTTP Connection Failed

Tags: objective-c, authentication, httpconnection

This is the function after clicked on the login button (to perform user authentication using http request / response)

```
(IBAction)loginbutton:(id)sender {
    @try {

        if([[userid text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[pass text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
        } else {
            NSString *GET =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"userid=%@&pass=%@",[userid text],[pass text]];
            NSLog(@"getData: %@",GET);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"192.168.1.14:8888/itrack/mobile/login.php"];

            NSData *getData;

            NSString *getLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@" ,@"userid" ,@"pass"];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request setValue:getLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:getData];

            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

                SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
                NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"%ld",(long)success);
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                    [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];


                } else {

                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
                }

            } else {
                if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
```

*Even though I enter the correct id and password, it keep showing me Connection Failed. Any idea how to solve this ?
Thanks a lot !*

Comment: you don't pass your get arguments to the url

Comment: how do i solve this ??